# UDP Listener Server Fails To Capture Incoming Data

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp

- I have a device with IP X.X.X.X which is not on the same
  network as my UDP Server.
- This device with IP X.X.X.X is sending packets with UDP protocol to
  my UDP Server.
- Packets are sent to port 5000 of my UDP Server
- WireShark is showing that my PC is receiving packets from the device.

  ```
  2711    351.573764  X.X.X.X  10.0.0.4   UDP 83    57514 → 5000   Len=61
  ```
- I want to capture the sent packets for processing.
- The following code is being taken from this [example](https://acrocontext.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/c-simple-udp-listener-in-asynchronous-way/) Currently, the moment program hits *Socket.BeginReceiveFrom*, Console application closes.

I believe that I'm missing something extremely basic, but I'm not able to see it now, so anything, tips or suggestions would be welcomed.

```
    static private Socket Socket;
    static private byte[] Buffer = new byte[1024];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartServer();
    }

    static public void StartServer()
    {
        //Setup the socket and message buffer
        Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000));

        //Start listening for a new message.
        EndPoint ClientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
        Socket.BeginReceiveFrom(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref ClientEndPoint, Receiver, Socket);
    }

    static private void Receiver(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        //Get the received message.
        Socket ReceiveSocket = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        EndPoint ClientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
        int MessageLength = ReceiveSocket.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref ClientEndPoint);
        byte[] localMsg = new byte[MessageLength];
        Array.Copy(Buffer, localMsg, MessageLength);

        //Start listening for a new message.
        EndPoint NewClientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
        Socket.BeginReceiveFrom(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref NewClientEndPoint, Receiver, Socket);

        // Do something here
    }
```

Comment: "Currently, the moment program hits Socket.BeginReceiveFrom, Console application closes." Well yes. The `BeginReceiveFrom` method starts receiving asynchronously, then returns. You then return from `StartServer` to `Main`, which then completes. At that point there are no foreground threads, and the process terminates. Why are you using an asynchronous method at all?

Comment: If all you want is to receive data, just call `ReceiveFrom()` instead of `BeginReceiveFrom()`. If you want to receive data asynchronously, using `BeginReceiveFrom()`, then you need to write a program that will stay running long enough for the receive operation to complete.

Comment: How would I loop it? What would be the best approach? Simple do..while true does not work in the example.